# Cant trigger empty view of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview where i want to show an text/image when it's empty but i cant find a way to make it work.

recyclerview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="ViolationFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".ViolationFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_violation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Empty" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = getActivity();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_violation_list, container, false);
    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Refresh items
            updateList();
        }
    });

    //Filters
    filterPaid = ((ViolationBrowser) context).filterPaid;
    filterUnpaid = ((ViolationBrowser) context).filterUnpaid;

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    TextView emptyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_empty);

    adapter = new ViolationAdapter(context, getData());
    adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new ViolationAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
            showDetailedViolationData(position);
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    if (adapter.getItemCount() >0) {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return view;
}
```

adapter

```
public class ViolationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViolationAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    List<ViolationItem> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViolationAdapter(Context context, List<ViolationItem> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_violation, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViolationItem current = data.get(position);
        holder.carName.setText(current.carName);
        holder.amount.setText(current.amount);
        holder.date.setText(current.date);

        if (current.payStatus == 2) holder.payStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.status_paid);
        else if (current.payStatus == 1)
            holder.payStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.status_part_paid);
        else holder.payStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.status_not_paid);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public ViolationItem getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public void addData(List<ViolationItem> data) {
        for (ViolationItem itm : data) {
            this.data.add(itm);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void clearData() {
        int size = data.size();
        data.clear();
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView carName, amount, date;
        ImageView payStatus, showAllDetails;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            carName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCarName);
            amount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAmount);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDate);
            payStatus = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.payStatus);
            showAllDetails = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.showAllDetails);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

What should i do to make it work? i still see an empty list instead of a text

Comment: please, post the code for ViolationAdapter

Comment: @LucasPaolillo added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the below condition should be like this:

```
if (adapter.getItemCount() <=0) 
{
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} 
else
{
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Also, in the xml layout:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Empty" />
```

Place the "list_empty" outside the SwipeRefreshLayout.

See below the complete example:
It shows empty view, if the recycler view is empty.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<String> arrayList = null;
MyAdapter mAdapter = null;
TextView list_empty;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.itemsRecyclerView);
    list_empty = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.list_empty);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mobile)));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    mAdapter = new MyAdapter((ArrayList<String>)arrayList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);       

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshContent();
        }
    });

}

private void refreshContent(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           arrayList.clear();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if(mAdapter.getItemCount()<=0)
            {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                list_empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                list_empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            // Stop refresh animation
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        };
    },2000);
}

class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> itemsData;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> itemsData) {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

   viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData.get(position));


    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtViewTitle;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            txtViewTitle = (TextView)
itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        }
    }


    // Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsData.size();
    }
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.test.demotest.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/itemsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Empty"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

item.xml:

```
<!-- title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this works almost great, except the SwipeRefreshLayout animation doesnt work well when the list is empty

Comment: I just stop refresh using  mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false), when I cleared the arraylist in method refreshContent().   Comment the line mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); or make mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true); .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that create a custom RecyclerView with multiple layouts. One layout with your normal recyclerview item and other layout as empty view with textView.

If your arraylist has items then show your usual layout else show the empty layout.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have solved this issue is to use a decoration.

```
public class ZeroStateDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int layoutId;
    private View view;
    private boolean enabled = true;

    public ZeroStateDecoration(@LayoutRes int layoutId) {
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (enabled && parent.getChildCount() == 0) {
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
            }

            view.measure(makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), makeMeasureSpec(parent.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
            view.layout(parent.getLeft(), parent.getTop(), parent.getRight(), parent.getBottom());
            view.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it simply add it to your RecyclerView with the layout id.

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ZeroStateDecoration(R.layout.zero_state);
```